# Can a country be expelled from NATO?

Tags: military, treaty, nato

It seems a country can leave NATO, seeing as France did so in 1966 (and rejoined in 2009), but can a country be expelled from NATO?

Who would make such a decision? Must all member countries vote FOR, or can someone within NATO (for example the Secretary General) veto such a decision? How would such a process be executed?